# New Relic-Blazemeter plugin

Tags: newrelic-platform, blazemeter

I am trying to install Blazemeter plugin into my New Relic account.
After providing the New Relic's API key in blazemeter, I am able to see the selected metrics in Blazemeter load test results. 
But there is no metrics loading up in my New Relic account as shown in the link:
http://blazemeter.com/blazemeter-announces-new-relic-performance-testing-plugin 
Please help!

Thanks,
Saswat

Answer (score 1):

I work for BlazeMeter and see you are already in touch with our support people regarding the same question.

On a side note, have you successfully run any tests **pulling** New Relic data into BlazeMeter?

The plugin let's you **push** BlazeMeter performance testing data to New Relic.

Thanks
Ophir

Comment: Yes, I am able to pull New Relic data in to Blazemeter account by providing the API key. I can see the test results in NewRelic tab inside blazemeter test results. But I am not seeing the blazemeter tab inside New Relic.

Comment: @user2214964 
Hi Saswat,  

I work with BlazeMeter as well. As per our support team, going forward, you will view BlazeMeter's data in your NewRelic account. Please note, this is a new (and AWESOME) feature which we are rolling out incrementally starting with paid accounts vs free tier accounts. As a free-tier user, this is why you weren’t able to see it right away.